# My Woocommerce shop page doesn't show correctly. Products are not arranged in similar pattern?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

My shop page look like this https://ibb.co/bBfEdF
It is showing like this here because some products have long product name & some have short. In the same way some products are having price mentioned and some are without price.
I have tried so many thing but couldn’t figure it out to set it automatically in same pattern, when I am making changes in the CSS files the changes are modifying other pages too, so I need to resolve this by without affecting other pages.
Can I set product names to be displayed always in one single line, weather the name is too short or long.
Either can I fix the box size for each row so that it look like similar for each product along with name.

Answer (score 0):

Its one of Woocommerce flaws. The fast solution is to give the product titles a similar word count

Comment: Thanks for the reply David, but I guess something is there to correct that flaw. Hope someone read it out and make the way clear for everyone.